# Java while- do code difficulties

Tags: java, while-loop

What is the problem with this,

```
public class Whileloop1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    if (x < 10) {
    System.out.print("x is less than 10!");
}
x++ ;
 }
}
```

I want the program to output the string as many times (10) until x gets to 10, and then stop printing the string. So to summarize, I want the string printed 10 times.

Can whoever answers this copy the code into their answer and fix  it? Thanks!

Comment: yes but i want it to succesfully end after x reaches 10

Comment: You have tagged this with while-loop, your description makes it clear you need to loop, yet have not put any loop into your code

Comment: Oh! that is because I accidentally changed the while to an if while speaking with someone! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your x++ needs to go in the curly brace and use a while loop

```
int x = 0;
while(x < 10) {
System.out.print("x is less than 10!");
 x++ ;
}
```

Comment: No problem....It appears you are just learning how to program, which is great! But if this is homework help, please I think its only right that you state that next time.

Comment: No it's not hw help im doing this entirely on my own. I'm trying to learn independently

Answer (score 4):

Here's partially how one would approach the problem of looping 10 times.

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10)
{
   //do something

   //Increment x by 1 [equivalent to: (x = x + 1)]
   x++;
}
```

Or if you know that the loop needs a fixed amount of iterations you could use a for-loop like so.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
   //do something
}
```